# Rspec command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, tdd

**What error I'm getting**

- `zsh: command not found: rspec`

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Run `$ rspec` inside my rails app

**What I've done so far**

1. Run `$ bundle`
2. Run `$ rails generate rspec:install`
3. Run `$ gem install rspec`
4. Run `$ sudo gem install rspec`
5. Run `$ bundle update rspec-rails`
6. Run  `$ bundle binstubs rspec-core`

**My Gemfile**

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails'

end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Below is the spec file I'm trying to execute using rspec**
[image]

**My setup**

- ruby 2.7.4p191
- Rails 6.1.4

By the way I'm not having any problem running my spec using `$ bundle exec rspec`. I'm just curious how can I test my specs using the command `$ rspec` which most likely I will be using all throughout my career as a rails developer.

Comment: For binstubs you want to use `bin/rspec`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `bundler`, most of the time you'll want to run gems under de bundled context; for `rspec` that is always true. You should either be using `bundle exec` (which you can alias to something shorter), or use the *binstub* with `bin/rspec`.

If you add `./bin` to your `PATH` environment variable, you can run binstubs without needing to prefix with `bin/`; so you could do just `rspec` to call the binstub.

Answer (score 0):

Prepending `bundle exec` tells the `bundler` to execute this command in context of the current bundle.

Try doing the following steps:-

`gem install rubygems-bundler`

`gem regenerate_binstubs`

Then try using `rspec` without `bundle exec`